H1B visa: Do I have to pay taxes on equity encashed from a company based abroad?
I am an Indian citizen and have been working as a Research Scientist on an H1B (lottery exempt) visa at a US university since November 2023. Prior to this, I was on a J-1 visa (Research Scholar) at a national lab in the US starting in 2018.
Before moving to the US, I was a consultant at a startup in Singapore and was awarded equity in the company. The equity vested over three years, and I am now eligible to cash it out. I would like to transfer the proceeds to my US bank account.
Since Singapore does not tax capital gains, I do not owe any taxes on this equity there.
I would like to know if I need to pay taxes on this equity in the US. If so, how should I report it to the IRS? Additionally, is receiving such income legal given my current H1B visa status? I am expecting to receive permanent residency in the US later this year. Should I wait to receive my green card before transferring the equity money from Singapore to my US bank account?
Regards,
RD


I would like to know if I need to pay taxes on this equity in the US.

Yes, if you're a US tax resident - your worldwide income is taxed by the US.

If so, how should I report it to the IRS?

It goes on your Schedule D of the Federal tax return (form 1040), just like any other capital gains.

Additionally, is receiving such income legal given my current H1B visa status?

There are no restrictions on ability to transact with your personal assets in any of the US visas, including H1b.

Should I wait to receive my green card before transferring the equity money from Singapore to my US bank account?

I don't think it matters for green card whether you have money in Singapore or not.

Very useful! Thank you.

How do I tell the IRS that this is long-term (>1 year) capital gain and subjected to lower taxes. The equity was awarded to me in 2018 and got vested in 2021. So, capital gains are after an year.

As I said - schedule d

Do you agree with another answer below which states that I do not have to pay any tax because "The sale transaction happened before moving to US"?

@r2d2 did it? You said "I'm now eligible to cash it"

That's right. I was given the equity in 2018 before I moved to the US but the equity was vested in 2021. I am now eligible to encash it.

@r2d2 if you were tax resident in the US in 2021 when it vested - it was taxable then. Capital gains from selling it now are also taxable.

Thanks. In 2021, the equity had no value though. I could not encash it then.

@r2d2 I don't know what "encash" means, and the equity clearly had value since you kept it and are able to sell it now. Anyway, you've got your answer. Transfer of funds is not a taxable event, vest and sale transactions are.

Many thanks! How do I computer the taxes on vesting? For sale, I guess I need to look at long-term capital gains tax. For vesting, how does it work? Also, I did not pay any tax on vesting in 2021 or later. So, how do I address it on my forms?

You might want to post separate questions, but first look through existing ones, I'm sure it's been asked before


Should I wait to receive my green card before transferring the equity money from Singapore to my US bank account?

No. The income is taxable at the moment you receive it, regardless of where in the world it happens.
Equity is complicated. Amount and timing of taxes depend a lot on the specifics of the equity (options vs grants, etc) type of vesting (cliff vesting vs monthly vesting, etc) and other details. There are certain "taxable" events in the life cycle of an equity (grant, vesting, exercise, sell) and the specifics of the equity determines what tax is due at which point. "Transfer to the US" itself is not a taxable event.
You may want to have a tax advisor take a look at your specific setup. It's possible that you should already have paid taxes on this in previous years and you would need to amend your past tax returns to sort this out.

Remittance to the US of this income from Singapore is not taxable in the US. However take care of the FBAR & FATCA reporting you may need to do as a US resident.

Thanks for your answer. This is capital gain. So, would I not be subjected to taxes in the US?

The sale transaction happened before moving to US. So if you are not a USC/GC then there is no question of US taxing you on this amount after your move to US.

But the equity was vested in 2021. Would that not be considered income after I came to the US?

The taxable event is the sale that happens now, not the vest that happened in 2021. The vest event should have been reported and taxes paid in 2021, when it happened, if you were already a US resident.
